# Firebase - Porque não executa o código do addOnCompleteListener

Tags: java, android, firebase

Como funciona o addOnCompleteListener, ele não é um listener que sera chamado quando a operação do signInWithEmailAndPassowrd for executado?
Ele entro um um login e senha correto e clico no botao ele chega até o task.addOnCompleteListener mas não entra no método onComplete.

```
Task<AuthResult> task = mFirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword());



                task.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Task<AuthResult> taskUser = task;
                        Log.i("app", "Sucesso - " + taskUser.isSuccessful());
                        if (taskUser.isSuccessful()) {
                            booSucessLogin = true;
                            mFirebaseInteractionLogin.sucessSiginUp(user);
                        }else{
                            booSucessLogin = false;
                            Log.i("app", "Falha - " + taskUser.getException().toString());

                            mFirebaseInteractionLogin.errorSiginUp("The email address is badly formatted", taskUser.getException());
                        }

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Estranho, testei em outro dispositivo e funcionou.

Vi alguns relatos do mesmo problema e pode ser também o `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:X.x.x` desatualizado no projeto.

Ou aínde pode ser o google play desatualizado no aplicativo!!!

Comment: Exactamente. Versões antigas do Firebase Auth ou do Google Play Services começam a apresentar problemas se não forem actualizadas.